# What is the max limit on databricks text widgets

Tags: azure-databricks, azure-notebooks

```
dbutils.widgets.text('input_query',"")
inquery= dbutils.widgets.get('input_query')
```

I tried to give a big string inside the text widget, it is not allowing to pass anything above 2048 characters. Is this a restriction in azure Dataricks text widgets

I have a scenario where a big select query string is passed as a base parameter from ADF via notebook activity.  at the moment if my select query string is  above 2048 characters , then it simply truncates anything above 2048 characters

Any thoughts on this ?

Comment: can you please confirm on what exact thing you are trying as passing query as input through widgets is not optimized method what I feel.

Comment: @KarthikeyanRasipalayDurairaj i also feel pasing a sql query via a ADF parameter to notebook activity is not a good apporach . But the requirement is a sql query needs to passed to notebook from ADF via notebook activity . now that sql query string  is big and has above 5000 chars

Comment: This SQLs would be dynamically will change ?

Comment: if not this SQLs not dynamically change , you can select SQLs based on some input value which be parameterized . Example , if var_number = 01 , choose this SQLs  and var_number variable can be parameterized. Just though process for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried calling notebook with string of length 50000 characters it worked successfully both in adf and adb notebook run.

[image]

When give 5000000 length then i got an error.

[image]

`com.databricks.WorkflowException: com.databricks.common.client.DatabricksServiceHttpClientException: INVALID_PARAMETER_VALUE: The provided parameters (in json representation) are too long (5000033 bytes); it cannot exceed 1048576 bytes.`

That means you can pass the parameter of size maximum of **1048576 bytes**.

So below are the possible solution for passing sql query.

As **@Karthikeyan Rasipalay Durairaj** said if your query is not dynamic then create a dictionary with key and value in the notebook you call, and pass the key in the parameters whichever query should be executed.

Code in notebook need to be called.

```
querys = {"1":"sql 1","2":"sql 2"}

import sys
dbutils.widgets.text('input_query',"")
inquery= dbutils.widgets.get('input_query')
f = f"{querys.get(inquery)} executed"
dbutils.notebook.exit(f)
```

call the notebook passing key as the parameter.

```
r = dbutils.notebook.run("/Users/v-jgs@microsoft.com/sql",timeout_seconds=120,arguments={"input_query":"1"})
print(r)
```

[image]

Or if you have a dynamic sql query you can try below approaches.

1. you can pass only the dynamic part of the query.

code:

```
dbutils.widgets.text('input_query',"")
inquery= dbutils.widgets.get('input_query')
f = f"select * from {inquery}"
dbutils.notebook.exit(f)
```

output:

[image]

3. Splitting the query to more number and pass them as parameters.

Let's assume below query.

```
SELECT
    u.user_id,
    u.first_name,
    u.last_name,
    u.email,
    u.phone_number,
    o.order_id,
    o.order_date,
    o.total_amount,
    o.shipping_address,
    o.payment_method
FROM
    users u
JOIN
    orders o ON u.user_id = o.user_id
WHERE
    o.order_date BETWEEN '2023-01-01' AND '2023-09-30'
ORDER BY
    u.last_name ASC, u.first_name ASC, o.order_date DESC;
```

I am splitting this at `JOIN`    and combined inside notebook called.
`part1,part2 = query.split("JOIN")`
Code in notebook called.

```
dbutils.widgets.text('input_query',"")
dbutils.widgets.text('input_query_sub',"")
inquery= dbutils.widgets.get('input_query')
inquery_sub= dbutils.widgets.get('input_query_sub')

f = "JOIN".join([inquery,inquery_sub])
print(f)
dbutils.notebook.exit("query executed")
```

Output:

[image]